# Why doesn't doxygen create a callgraph of my C++ code?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have downloaded source code from the following site: https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/master/modules/control/integration_tests/simple_control_test.cc and I want to analyze how the modules of the code interact with each other. Therefore, I did a web search and found Doxygen can do such things. I followed exactly the steps described in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgVgZjaeNkw
However, when I navigate to the "html" folder as the shown in the tutorial above and click on the index.html file I get this:

[image: The results that Oxygen returns]

As you can see there is no files tab (as in the video) or any info about the code at all. Did I forget something? What can I do?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case it is quite important to know: is the code documented? Which settings did you use in the Doxyfile that are different from the standard Doxyfile?

Comment: "Learn C++ and ..." - know that that is a easily a *multi year* project. And if you want to up it to "learn C++ *well* ", it's *easily* a 5+ year project (learning/doing it full time) - C++ is a large and *complicated* beast and difficult to master.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comments! I will provide a minimal, complete, and verfiable example as soon as I can. I know that learning C++ is a multi-year project. But what do you do if your job is to understand some hundred thousand lines of code that are undocumented? Well, I try to do my best ...

Comment: Do you have graphviz installed on your system? As far as I remember it is required by doxygen if you want to generate callsgraphs.

Comment: Yes, I have graphviz installed. Thanks for bringing this up (edited my question)!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely problem is that not the correct settings have been used as probably the code is not documented for doxygen.

Required settings to YES:

- HAVE_DOT
- CALL_GRAPH
- CALLER_GRAPH
- EXTRACT_ALL
- EXTRACT_PRIVATE
- EXTRACT_PACKAGE
- EXTRACT_STATIC
- EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES
- EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS
- EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES
- RECURSIVE

for the meaning of these variables see the doxygen manual (also for many more possibilities).

I just did a test in the root directory, created here a default doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile):

- `doxygen -g`

and edited the file:

- set `INPUT                  = apollo-master/modules/common`
- other variables mentioned above except the `RECURSIVE` to `YES`

I ran the doxygen (`doxygen`) and started the results: `html\index.html` on Windows on a *nix system with Firefox  `firefox html/index.html`, typed in the 'doxygen search windows' (top right) `ExportFlags` and clicked on the result and I got the documentation of the function `ExportFlags` including a call and a caller graph.

Comment: Thank you albert! Indeed, some of these variables have not been set to YES. However, they are now, and this did not solve the problem. I understand what a minimal, complete, verifiable example is. However, it is pretty hard for me to provide one here. The only thing I might be able to provide though is the complete source code (which so far I do not know anything about). It is open source: https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/master/modules/control/integration_tests/simple_control_test.cc What else can I provide to have a better question? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Based on the comment from GSIO01: do you get any warning / error messages (except of course the "not documented" ones?). Furthermore I see you reference to a test module (integration_tests), better to look at the source code itself first, the test framework uses probably some macro settings  that are hard to grasp in the beginning.

Comment: As you ar also new to C++ it is not the best to start straight away with such complex code. To have a MCVE is to start with 1 or 2 small files to get some things working and gain experience with some tools.

Comment: Thank you for your comments albert. No, I do not get any warnings. Everything is working as it is supposed to, I just do not get any information about the code structure. And thanks for the tip to look at it myself first. Given the fact that my question seems to have be put on hold in the meantime (which I find sad considering that I am describing everything of the problem that I know but that's not the topic, right?), I'll do it all by hand. I do not know anything about the files not even if, e.g. the file "integration_tests", actually is a test module. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Btw, can I use any kind of file to start with these 1, 2 small files to gain experience? Or do the files actually have to relate to each other (which would mean that I need to find two such files or create such files))?

Comment: I would start with the files in one directory e.g. common and extend this slowly with some subdirectories, maybe also look at the configuration setting "RECURSIVE"

Comment: See my additions to the answer.

Comment: Thank you albert. I'll start with common and let you know ...

Comment: I just found out that the software is made of different types of languages. Before I start and invest a lot of time to get familiar with Doxygen. Is Doxygen limited to analyzing one specifically given language?

Comment: Albert, how do I create a default oxygen config file? What you did was create the file, and write the following lines into it, right?

Comment: how do I create a default oxygen config file? What you did was create the file, and write a line with "INPUT =", and a line for each of the other variables "= YES" into it, right?

Comment: I tried it now just with the common module, too and I got some more results. Might that have to do with the fact that there are other languages in the other files, too?

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the doxygen manual, especially the basic stuff. Here you will also see how to invoke doxygen, supported languages modification of the Doxyfile (and generating the default version). also doxygen --help might help you.